# Panda DataFrame Passing in Parameters For Plotting

Tags: python, pandas, parameter-passing

For any pandas DataFrame, say

```
df
```

I can plot relevant information using

```
df.plot()
```

but on the pandas site for plotting: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html, I am looking for a way to reduce the size of legend; it's simply too big. How would I be able to do that?

Do I use the kwds argument?

The plotting site above states that I can use kwds in the following way:

"kwds : keywords
Options to pass to matplotlib plotting method"

How do I use that exactly? Do I use a dictionary? How can I make it so that this option refers to the legend, ie, something like

```
plt.legend(['foo'],prop={'size':13})
```

for the fontsize of the legend, which makes it smaller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DataFrame.plot()` returns the `Axes` object, you can then call `ax.legend()` to modifiy the settings:

```
ax = df.plot()
ax.legend(prop={'size':10})
```

Comment: I have the same question as alvarezcl but unfortunately your response doesn't really answer it. How do you use the kwds argument to pass a plot setting (say alpha level of points) from pandas.DataFrame.plot to matplotlib.pyplot.plot? The pandas docs indicates you can do this using the kwds keyword but I understand how.

Comment: Agreed, this response does not answer the question, although it is accepted. I am still looking for the syntax for passing keywords in a pandas plot, but there is not a single example around that shows how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to do anything special to pass `**kwds` (see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters) to understand the `**` notation better).

All arguments that are not positional arguments of the [DataFrame.plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) method will be passed to the [pyplot.plt](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot) method automatically.

Note: `kwds` stands for keyword arguments, so you have to use `arg_name = arg_value`.

You might have already used it without knowing, for example in `df.plot(alpha=0.5)`: alpha is not a positional argument of `DataFrame.plot`, so it is passed to `pyplot.plt`.

You can see it when trying `aalpha`: the error stack points to matplotlib, not pandas.

--

Note: the `label` argument does not work as is.

In the [pandas code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.20.3/pandas/plotting/_core.py#L1640-L1696), you can see that the legend labels are automatically generated from the column names, except when the `y` argument is explicitly passed. It makes sense, as `y` can only be a single column, where `DataFrame.plot` allows you to plot all the columns at once. But `label` does not accept a list of values, so there is no way to know which label to update.

It means that you have three options. Either pass a single column name as `y`: in that case `label` will work as intended. Or update the legend afterward (see the [legend guide](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html) for reference). Or use the single-column DataFrame as a Series.

--

**Edit about the original question**: the `**kwds` arguments are passed to `pyplot.plt`, that has no direct link to the legend. So it is not possible to update the legend properties with `DataFrame.plot`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
df.plot().legend(prop={'size':10})
```

You can also pass more parameters (this will place legend outside of the plot):

```
df.plot().\
    legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5))
```